# How can I close the gap in the mouth?

Tags: modeling

I'm following the blenderella tutorial and I'm at the point where she closes the gap. But I'm copying the tutorial but somehow the mouth gap is still open. How can I close it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While in *edit mode*, press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  and select *Edge*. Then press  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the edge loop in question. Finally, press  <kbd>F</kbd>  to create a new face.

Alternatively, you may be able to select the upper and lower edges, bring them closer together until they're nearly touching and press  <kbd>W</kbd>  then remove doubles, and adjust your merge distance in the operator panel until you are satisfied with the results.

You may also want to use proportional editing for this kind of task. Press <kbd>O</kbd> to enable it, then use the scroll wheel to adjust the strength during a transform operation.