# How can I fill these gap of the verticals?

Tags: mesh

I don't want to fill it with F. I want to select the edge and snap it to the other edge adjacent to it.

[image]

Comment: "permanently stick to the other vertical" sound kinda unclear what you want to do. Do you mean to have the selected edge snap to the other edge adjacent to it? it would be nice if you post the image with some arrows drawn on it to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close the gap in the mouth?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44305/how-can-i-close-the-gap-in-the-mouth)

Comment: That question is different.

Comment: @Mooneon do you have a _Mirror Modifier_ on this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Edit Mode* switch to *vertex select*, select the first vertex <kbd>RMB</kbd> the target vertex <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> to open the merge popup and select last.

[image]

Repeat this for the second vertex of the edge in question. Another method is to use snapping and auto-merge (this is better when you have to stich a lot of vertices).